# How to manage state for multiple dropdowns

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have a add button. When user clicks it, a dropdown menu will be open and user can select item from the dropdown. If user clicks the add button again, another dropdown menu will open and users can select item from the dropdown. These dropdowns have the same options. How can I manage the state for these dropdowns? Ideally I would like to have the items selected from each dropdown in the same array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Manage a state based on add button click and based on that state, change the options that are shown in drop-downs.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to create new component.

```
<div className="w-full flex flex-col">
    {disciplinesDropdowns.length > 0 &&
      disciplinesDropdowns.map((disciplines, index) => (
        <InputItem key={index} index={index} 
          handleRemoveDropdownClick= {handleRemoveDropdownClick} 
          handleInputChange= {handleInputChange}
        /> // add all props you want
      ))}

    <div className="mt-4">
      <button
        className="flex items-center"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setDisciplinesDropdowns((prev) => [
            ...prev,
            disciplinesMenu,
          ]);
        }}
      >
        <Icon icon="plus-circle" />
        <span className="ml-1">                              add another  discipline</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

...

const InputItem = (props) => {
    const [itemState, setItemState] = useState();
       return(
         <div className="mt-4" key={index}>
          <article className="flex justify-between">
            <label htmlFor="otherDisciplines">
              Discipline {index + 1}
            </label>
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                props.handleRemoveDropdownClick(index);
              }}
              className="text-orange-50 text-sm "
            >
              REMOVE
            </button>
          </article>
          <select
            defaultValue="select your discipline"
            name={`otherDisciplines_${props.index + 1}`}
            // onChange={handleSelectDisciplineClick}
            onChange={props.handleInputChange}
            className="w-11/12 mt-2 h-10 sm:h-12 px-4 text-black-87 rounded-md ml-4"
          >
            <option disabled value="select your discipline">
              -select your discipline-
            </option>
            {disciplines.map((discipline) => (
              <option key={discipline.id}              value={discipline.name}>
                {discipline.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
    );

}
```

Comment: Hi @Expressed3V! Thanks for the suggestion. What Can I do with the itemState?

Comment: You can add any state(reusable) you want. When you set the state, It will be limited to the child component. i.e. when you set a value with the input change handler, It will be saved on the child component. And after the complete the form, you can send the fulfilled result to the parent component and add field to the list.